# Pass unknown number of object properties

Tags: javascript, object

need to write a function that will accept unknown object properties and pass them to another plugins function. Problem is how to retrieve given arguments, and pass them further?

**example:**

```
function(obj) {
 other_function(obj)
}
```

obj should accept it in form ***{ arrows: true, size: '250' ... }*** etc. and pass it to other function in the same form.
problem is how to pass them like that? I can make default values of all parameters, but it would make no sense if it is a large group, and if someone adds new parameters to other_function :)

thanks in advance!

Comment: Is `other_function` defined like `function other_function(arrows, size, ...)`; do I understand you correctly? Your code as it stands would work if both functions just accept an object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the `arguments` property you can pass to ***any function*** extra arguments:

```
function someFunction() {
    alert(arguments[0] + ' ' + arguments[1] + ' ' + arguments[2]));
}


someFunction('hello', 'foo', 'bar');
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `arguments` propery which is implicit but available in all functions.

```
function(obj) {
     other_function(arguments);
 }
```

[Read more about it at MDN.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Functions_and_function_scope/arguments)